# Finding Drag coefficient for flows with both Laminar and Turbulent part

Tags: fluid-mechanics

How will we find the overall drag coefficient for a steady flow which is laminar initially and then becomes turbulent after a critical distance?
[image]

Comment: Are you going to do some weighted average by time in each domain?

Comment: I have assumed steady flow. So won't be using time average. I have also put up different approaches to the question which i feel can be used but don't know which is correct